# MongoDB - Split a Document with an Array of Subdocuments into 2 documents, with half the Subdocuments in each

Tags: arrays, mongodb, split, subdocument

Good day all,

I have a set of documents which are hitting the BSON size limit due to the number of items in an array of Subdocuments. I'm trying to apply a new field to these subdocuments as part of a schema update but it's failing on these specific documents because the new field pushes the BSON size limit over.

What I want to do is effectively split the Document(s) in 'half' based on the array of subdocuments, so I would have Document1 (the original) with the array now containing (for example) subdocuments 1-2, and Document1B having the array containing 3-4.

Here is an example of the basic layout

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"), 
    "DocumentId" : "0000001", 
    "Items" : [
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ItemType" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ClassType" : "1", 
            "Created" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:13:22.000+0000"), 
            "LastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-03-12T15:52:39.000+0000") 
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(2), 
            "ItemType" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ClassType" : "1", 
            "Created" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:13:22.000+0000"), 
            "LastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-03-12T15:52:39.000+0000") 
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(3), 
            "ItemType" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ClassType" : "1", 
            "Created" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:13:22.000+0000"), 
            "LastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-03-12T15:52:39.000+0000") 
        }, 
        {
            "ItemId" : NumberInt(4), 
            "ItemType" : NumberInt(1), 
            "ClassType" : "1", 
            "Created" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:13:22.000+0000"), 
            "LastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-03-12T15:52:39.000+0000") 
        }, 
    ], 
    "Priority" : NumberInt(0), 
    "Status" : NumberInt(3), 
    "FileChecksum" : "ca1fbd9c8e1669bcf4155657d3600fa4", 
    "CreatedBy" : "anonymous.user@test.com", 
    "LastUpdatedBy" : null, 
    "AssignedBy" : "anonymous.user@test.com", 
    "DeletedBy" : null, 
    "LastUpdated" : ISODate("2020-03-12T15:52:39.000+0000"), 
    "Created" : ISODate("2012-03-13T08:13:23.000+0000"), 
    "Assigned" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:10:48.000+0000"), 
    "Completed" : ISODate("2012-03-13T11:13:22.000+0000"), 
    "DeletedDate" : null, 
    "AssignedTo" : "anonymous.user@test.com", 
    "RejectionReason" : null, 
    "Deleted" : false, 
    "DeletionReason" : null
}
```

Comment: did $slice not work in this situation?

Comment: I haven't been able to effectively use $slice to permanently split the results. Currently, I'm exporting the docs to JSON and physically splitting in half, then re-importing them. Creates a new copy of the second half and overwrite the original doc with the first half. It's labor intensive but it's working

Comment: Which version of MongoDB?

Comment: Currently using version 4.2.8

Comment: use $slice and $merge in an aggregation pipeline